# Python pandas | how to assign keywords extracted from a column to another column?

Tags: python, string, pandas, keyword

I have a pandas dataframe as below with text string in each tuple:

```
  Text Col
-----------
I have an apple.
She eats orange.
Tom likes banana and orange
```

I would like to extract the key word from the "Text Col" and assign the keyword as value in another column "keyword col"

```
  Text Col                              KeyWord
-----------------------------------------------------
I have an apple.                        apple
She eats orange.                        orange
Tom likes banana and orange             banana, orange
```

I only know that I can check if the string contains specific keywords
`df['Text Col'].str.contains('apple|orange|banana')`
but I don't know how to assign the keyword contained in the column to another column.

Have googled but didnt have any similar question.
Would someone please kindly help me with this?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.str.extract`, e.g.

```
df['Text Col'].str.extract('(apple|orange|banana)', expand = False)
```

or `.extractall` followed by `.unstack` if you expect more than one match:

```
matches = df['Text Col'].str.extractall('(apple|orange|banana)').unstack()
```

You'll need to join them; if your dataset is small, you can do this in pure Python:

```
df['extracted'] = [','.join(filter(None,li)) for li in matches.values]
```

If you insist on doing this in pandas, you can use a loop over the columns, though it looks messy:

```
df['extracted'] = ''
for _,col in matches.fillna('').iteritems():
    df['extracted'] += col + ','
df['extracted'] = df['extracted'].str.rstrip(',')
```

Comment: Hello ken wei, thanks for your answer. I tried this code yet unfortunately this code returns only one word when a string contains multiple keywords. for example for the text "Tom likes banana and orange " it returns only banana but both "banana, orange". Is it possible to get multiple keywords returned at the same time?

Comment: Thanks so much!! I am not so familiar with text processing in python and was about to write a loop to do this... this saves me a lot of time thanks so much